# Effective divisor gives a monomorphism $O_X \hookrightarrow O_X(D)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

The following sentences is in Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra by Bosch，page 442.

> If $D$ is effecitve and $f_i \in O_X(U_i)$ for all $i \in I$, the sheaf $O_X(D)$ may be interpreted as the sheaf of meromorphic functions having "poles" of a type not worse than indicated by the divisor $D$. **In particular, the unit section of $O_X$ then gives rise to a global section in $O_X(D)$ and, hence, to a monomorphism $O_X \hookrightarrow  O_X(D)$.**

My question is what's **the unit section of $O_X$** he means? and how to get a monomorphism from this unit section?

Any hint is welcome, thanks!

Comment: It's $1$. The map is given by sending $1\mapsto 1$.

Comment: @KReiser Oh, thanks!

Comment: where are you using $f$ in your question? @KReiser pls correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the map $1 \mapsto s$ for some global section $s \in \mathcal{O}(D)$?

Comment: @Sisi maybe we use the fact that $f_i \in O_X(U_i)$, so $1$ is a global section of $O_X(D)$, but maybe I'm wrong..

Comment: its definitely not a global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$! This is not even a ring, but just a module over $\mathcal{O}_X$. It looks locally like $f_i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ so elements are like $a/f_i^k$ for $a \in \mathcal{O}(U_i)$, so there is no $1$.

Comment: @Sisi we're taking $s=1$ here. For an effective Cartier divisor $D$, we always have that $1$ is a global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$.

Comment: ok I'm confused, will need to think about this!! but thanks anyways!

Comment: ok I see now: you take $\mathcal{O}(-D) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ the inclusion of the ideal sheaf and then take the dual map to $\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(D)$ where you call $1=1_D$ the image of $1\in \mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: @Sisi That doesn't sound right to me. Recall that (as mentioned in the post above) the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ are rational functions with divisor of poles less than or equal to $D$. $1$ is clearly such a function, so it's a global section. (Also, when you don't use an [@-reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) other users will not generally be notified of your comments.)

Comment: @KReiser alright, it makes sense now to me, thank you!